# insert sort with doubly linked list

Tags: c, sorting, linked-list

I've been working on a set of functions for doubly linked lists, one that I've had trouble with is inserting elements into the list but keeping the list in sorted order. So if I have a list of {3, 4, 6} and insert 5 then the list will become {3, 4, 5, 6}

I just finished the latest code after rewriting it last night, please comment and tell me if there is a better way, I am posting both the header file and the c file. One thing I want to point out is that I do not use a pointer to the current node and only create one pointer in the insert function that creates a new node with a temp placement.

LIST.H

```
/* custom types */

typedef struct node
{
    int val;
    struct node * next;
    struct node * prev;
}Node;

typedef struct list
{
    Node * head;
    Node * tail;
}List;

/* function prototypes */

/* operation: creates a list */
/* pre: set equal to a pointer to a list*/
/* post: list is initialized to empty */
List* NewList();

/* operation: Insert a number into a list sorted */
/* pre: plist points to a list, num is an int */
/* post: number inserted and the list is sorted */
void Insert(List * plist, int x);
```

LIST.C

```
/* c file for implentation of functions for the custome type list */
/* specifically made for dueling lists by, Ryan Foreman */

#include "List.h"
#include <stdlib.h> /* for exit and malloc */
#include <stdio.h>

List* NewList()
{
    List * plist = (List *) malloc(sizeof(List));
    plist->head = NULL;
    plist->tail = NULL;
    return plist;
}

void Insert(List * plist, int x)
{
    /* create temp Node p then point to head to start traversing */
    Node * p = (Node *) malloc(sizeof(Node));
    p->val = x;

    /* if the first element */
    if ( plist->head == NULL) {
        plist->head = p;
        plist->tail = p;
    }
    /* if inserting into begining */
    else if ( p->val < plist->head->val ) {
        p->next = plist->head;
        plist->head->prev = p;
        plist->head = p;
    }

    else {
        p->next = plist->head;
        int found = 0;
        /* find if there is a number bigger than passed val */
        while((p->next != NULL) && ( found == 0)) {
            if(p->val < p->next->val)
                found = 1;
            else {
                p->next = p->next->next;
            }
        }
        /* if in the middle of the list */
        if(found == 1)
        {
            p->prev = p->next->prev;
            p->next->prev = p;
        }
        /* if tail */
        else {
            plist->tail->next = p;
            p->prev = plist->tail;
            plist->tail = p;
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you for any input on the code, any comments are appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Some comments on your C' utilisation.

- In C, cast from pointer to `void` to pointer to object is unecessary.
- It could be a good idea to check `malloc` return in such library.

Comment: > Which function is casting from pointer to void to point to object? How can I fix that? 
> I will add error checking to make sure malloc is able to allocate memory as well, I had forgotten about that haha

Comment: malloc returns a void*. No need to cast its return value.

Answer (score 1):

malloc() does not zero memory, you don't set your first nodes next/prev, so your while loop could go on forever if second node >= first node value, ie exit condition p->next != NULL is not met.

Comment: Thank you, I just added setting both next/prev to NULL but can you clarify what you mean by 'malloc() does not zero memory'?

Comment: It allocates you a free chunk of memory without zero-ising (filling each natural chunk [byte, int, long] with null (0), it before it hands it over to your caller - calloc on the other hand will zeroise memory (see man malloc). There are sometimes, (when you want to initialise it yourself), that malloc is usefull, since it doesn't bear the overhead of zeroisation, other times you just want a clean allocation.

Comment: If this answers you question, could you indicate and close the question. Thanks